# How can I override `_GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT` used by a third party library?

Tags: python, pytest, tavern

I am using `tavern` to test python flask application. Occasionally, I got http connection errors like:

```
for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
    af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res
    sock = None
    try:
        sock = socket.socket(af, socktype, proto)

        # If provided, set socket level options before connecting.
        _set_socket_options(sock, socket_options)

        if timeout is not socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT:
            sock.settimeout(timeout)
        if source_address:
            sock.bind(source_address)
>       sock.connect(sa)
E       **ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused**
```

One possible reason is that the connection is timed out so I'd like to change the timeout for http connection used by `tavern`. I can't find a configuration from `tavern` for changing this value but based on the source code above, it seems that the default timeout is read from `socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT`. How can I change this value from my app? I don't call this connection method directly which is called by `Tavern` framework. Is there a way to update it from my app side?
I am using `pytest` to run the test so it is also good if I can set something on `pytest` to override this value.

Comment: Have you tried assigning a different value to `socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT`? Since modules are cached, the change would effectively be global.